# how to insert all pinned messages to a file?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@commands.command()
async def pins(self, ctx,channel:discord.TextChannel):
    pins=await channel.pins()
    f = BytesIO(bytes(str(pins), encoding="utf-8"))
    file = discord.File(fp=f, filename="pins.txt")
    await ctx.send(file=file)
```

Hey so I'm trying to make a command where it will get all pinned messages of a channel and insert the into a file.

My problem is that `await channel.pins()` does not display the pinned messages.Instead it displays information about the message and the channel.

```
Message id=823211324343245892304 channel=<TextChannel id=7242345725488373823 name='channel' position=2 nsfw=True news=False category_id=724975728488373821> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=8048242432231802419 name='author's name'
```

How can I display all the pinned messages into the file?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextChannel.pins` returns a list of `discord.Message` instances, you can loop through them and only get the message content and/or other information about the message, a simple example would be:

```py
pins = await channel.pins()
data = '\n'.join([f"[{m.created_at}][{m.author}]: {m.content}" for m in pins])
buffer = BytesIO(bytes(data, encoding="utf-8"))
f = discord.File(buffer, filename="pins.txt")
await ctx.send(file=f)
```

The `data` variable is just a list joined with a newline as the delimiter which displays the message data in a nice way (feel free to change it as you wish).

#### Reference:

- [`TextChannel.pins`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.pins)

Comment: Thank you.You are right i should have read the docs better and then asked.Will add you comment as an answer in 5m